# mongoose mongodb query find

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

i'm new in mongo and mongoose.

i want to do a simple query in relational database but i have strong problems to do in mongo

here is me schema:

```
const GroupSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String , required:true},
    image: { type: String , required:true},
    location : {type:String , required: true},
    locationCode: {type:String , required:true },
    created: {type:Date, default:Date.now() , required:true },
    createdBy: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref:'User' , required:true},
    //category: [{type:String,enum:[ config.TYPES ]}],
    pendingUsers: [
        {   text:String, 
            user:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref: 'User'}
        }
    ],
    rejectedUsers: [ {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref: 'User'} ],
    users: [ {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref: 'User' , required:true } ],
    adminUsers:[{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref:'User', required:true}],
    events :[Event],
    activity:[Activity]
})
```

and i my controller file i want to do the following query:

```
let groupId = '123123hgvhgj
let userId = 'asdfsadf3434

Group.find()
    .where('_id').equals(groupId)
    .where('pendingUsers.user')
    .in(userId)
.where('users')
    .in(userId)
.where('adminUsers')
    .in(userId)
.where('rejectedUsers')
    .in(userId)
    .exec(function (err, records) {
        //make magic happen
        console.log(records)
    });
```

i have to get the record WHERE _id match with a group id AND (userId exists in pendingUsers OR userid exists in rejectedUsers OR userid exists in users OR userid exists in adminUsers )

i know that seems to be a simple query but returns empty when should be returned the record i have something wrong in the query?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Group.find({
        $and: [
            { _id: groupId},
            {
                $or: [
                    { "pendingUsers": { $elemMatch: { "user": userId } } },
                    //{ 'pendingUsers.user' : { $elemMatch: {userId} } },
                    { rejectedUsers: { $elemMatch: {userId} } },
                    { users: { $elemMatch: {userId} } },
                    { adminUsers: { $elemMatch: {userId} } },
                ]
            }
        ]
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if mongoose seems to support some simple and + or operations ([docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-and))
it seems to me as if you would still need to mix some pure mongodb query into it.

Considering that, i would go with a pure mongodb style query. This one should fit your needs(untested) or will at least point you in the right direction:

```
Group.find({
    $and: [
        {_id: groupId},
        {
            $or: [
                { pendingUsers.user: { $elemMatch: {userId} } },
                { rejectedUsers: { $elemMatch: {userId} } },
                { users: { $elemMatch: {userId} } },
                { adminUsers: { $elemMatch: {userId} } },
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: thanks, i have to change it a bit : `Group.find({
  $and: [
   { _id: groupId},
   {
    $or: [
     { "pendingUsers": { $elemMatch: { "user": userId } } },
     //{ 'pendingUsers.user' : { $elemMatch: {userId} } },
     { rejectedUsers: { $elemMatch: {userId} } },
     { users: { $elemMatch: {userId} } },
     { adminUsers: { $elemMatch: {userId} } },
    ]
   }
  ]
 })`